# How to modify the core WordPress admin menu to load via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I cannot find any plugin that does this, nor any thread with someone asking this, so it's either very difficult or very simple.

**Note:**
This is not for ajax loading panel/tabs menus within an admin page, this is for the entire WP backend admin menu, regardless of speed and potential issues. Menu Items such as: Dashboard, Pages, Posts, Users, etc.

I asked GPT3.5 and this is what I got, could someone confirm if this would be the right way to do it?

1. **Enqueue jQuery in your theme or plugin:** Ensure that jQuery is enqueued in your theme or plugin. WordPress includes jQuery by default, but you might want to check and enqueue it explicitly if needed.

phpCopy code

```php
function enqueue_custom_scripts() { 
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_scripts');
```

2. **Create a JavaScript file for your AJAX functionality:** Create a JavaScript file (e.g., **`custom-admin-ajax.js`**) and enqueue it in your theme or plugin. This file will contain your AJAX logic.

javascriptCopy code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    // AJAX request to load WordPress admin menu 
    $.ajax({ 
        url: ajaxurl, 
        data: { action: 'load_admin_menu', }, 
        success: function(response) { 
            // Update the menu with the response 
            $('#adminmenuwrap').html(response); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

3. **Create a PHP function to handle the AJAX request:** In your theme's **`functions.php`** file or in your custom plugin, add a PHP function to handle the AJAX request.

phpCopy code

```php
function load_admin_menu_callback() { 
    // Your code to generate the admin menu 
    ob_start(); 
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/menu-header.php'; // Include WordPress menu header 
    $menu = ob_get_clean();  // Send the generated menu as the AJAX response 
    echo $menu; wp_die(); // Always include this to terminate the script properly 
} 
add_action('wp_ajax_load_admin_menu', 'load_admin_menu_callback');
```

In this example, we use **`ob_start()`** to buffer the output of **`menu-header.php`** and then send it as the AJAX response.

4. **Hook the JavaScript file and localize AJAX URL:** Enqueue your JavaScript file and localize the AJAX URL in your theme's **`functions.php`** or in your custom plugin.

phpCopy code

```php
function enqueue_custom_scripts() { 
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-admin-ajax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-admin-ajax.js', array('jquery'), null, true); wp_localize_script('custom-admin-ajax', 'ajaxurl', admin_url('admin-ajax.php')); 
} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_scripts');
```

The **`wp_localize_script`** function is used to pass data from PHP to JavaScript. In this case, we're passing the **`ajaxurl`** variable which contains the URL to **`admin-ajax.php`**.

Now, when the page loads, it will trigger an AJAX request to **`admin-ajax.php`** with the action **`load_admin_menu`**. The server will respond with the generated admin menu, and the JavaScript will update the menu on the page.

I tried to find a Plugin or Theme that would do this for the backend, but Menu Editor Pro doesn't do it, and Adminify only ajax load the sub-menu items, but reloads the page when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should work, may need a tweak but you'll need to run it.

ob_start function allows you to load a PHP file but not include it in any output, as it gets buffered.

ob_end_clean function gets that buffers contents, so that line puts the content into a variable.

You might just want to find where it normally loads in the template and comment it out/replace it with your response.

In general it looks good.